# Is Banach's Isomorphism theorem an if-and-only-if?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The following is from the book by Bryan P. Rynne, Martin A. Youngson - Linear Functional Analysis-Springer (2008)

**Definition 4.34**
Let $X, Y$ be normed linear spaces. An operator $T \in B(X, Y )$ is said to be
invertible if there exists $S \in B(Y, X)$ such that $S\circ T = I_X, T \circ S = I_Y$ , in which
case $S$ is the inverse of $T$ and is denoted by $T^{-1}$

**Corollary 4.45** (Banach’s Isomorphism Theorem)
If X, Y are Banach spaces and $T \in B(X, Y )$ is bijective, then $T$ is invertible

My professor is following this book and she wrote after stating this Corollary that

If T is not  injective $\implies$ T is not invertible **... (1)**

If T is not surjective $\implies$ T is not invertible **...(2)**

If T is injective and surjective $\implies$ T is  invertible **... (3)**

(3) is just what the corollary says. But I am not comfortable with (1) and (2), they don't seem to be logical conclusions of the corollary. The corollary says bijectivity implies invertibility, not the other way around and the contrapositive is that non invertibility implies non bijectivity so

If T is not  invertible $\implies$ T is not injective... (1')

If T is not invertible $\implies$ T is not surjective...(2')

are all what I could deduce from the corollary by using contraposition

**(1) and (2) don't follow by contraposition from  the corollary, so if they are true they don't follow from this corollary, do they?**
**If they are true I wonder why is that the book states only one implication and where they come from. Since we are in infinite dimension and things could be different from the finite dimensional case, I don't dare to think that the corollary is an if and only if, is it?**

Comment: For $S\circ T=I_X, T\circ S=I_Y$ to hold, both $S$ and $T$ must be bijective - this is just a general property of functions.

Comment: @StinkingBishop  So the eventually infinite dimensions of the spaces don't matter and the theorem is actually an iff. Perhaps the books wants to stress the given implication?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Right. The book stresses the non-trivial implication, the one that has to do with Banach spaces as opposed to being an elementary property of arbitrary sets.